# Creating a new key from child elements in Json with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I want to create new key from child values inside the json with ES6/ES5. I tried with arrow functions but i couldn't get the result. Firstly you can see my part of json in below,

```
[  
   {  
      matchId:307,
      matchStatusId:5,
      matchHomeScore:0,
      matchAwayScore:0,
      matchTime:0,
      homeClubId:608,
      homeClub:{  
         clubId:608,
         clubName:"Annaba"
      },
      awayClubId:609,
      awayClub:{  
         clubId:609,
         clubName:"Bazer Sakhra"
      },
      leagues:[  
         {  
            leagueId:65,
            parentLeagueId:null,
            leagueName:"ALGERIA"
         },
         {  
            leagueId:66,
            parentLeagueId:65,
            leagueName:"Algeria Cup"
         }
      ]
   },
]
```

I want to create new parent key. It will get the values from values of child items and it will combine. Child item numbers changeable. Not everytime 2 items.
**leaguesGeneral:"ALGERIA - Algeria Cup"**

```
   leaguesGeneral:"ALGERIA - Algeria Cup"   
   leagues: [  
      {  
         leagueId:65,
         parentLeagueId:null,
         leagueName:"ALGERIA"
      },
      {  
         leagueId:66,
         parentLeagueId:65,
         leagueName:"Algeria Cup"
      }
   ]
```

I found this method. But it combines everything from the parent.

```
data = data.map(function (x) {
    var keys = Object.keys(x);
    x.newKeyValue = keys.map(key => x[key]).join('-');
    return x;
});
```

Comment: Do you have an example of expected output based upon your example JSON?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want to accomplish here. What should be in the resulting JSON?

Comment: You can use below code `data.forEach(o => o.leaguesGeneral = o.leagues.map(({leagueName}) => leagueName).join(' - '));`

Comment: I explained with example. I want to create looks like this `leaguesGeneral:"ALGERIA - Algeria Cup"`

Comment: @MehmetDemiray Do you want to keep all the rest of the original JSON object, or just the leaguesGeneral and leagues parts?  It's unclear.

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes i want to keep all. I dint't write all codes again :) Only i want to create one more key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `leaguesGeneral` key can be added to each object in the array using

```
o.leagues.map(({ leagueName }) => leagueName).join(' - ')
```

```js
const data = [  
   {  
      matchId:307,
      matchStatusId:5,
      matchHomeScore:0,
      matchAwayScore:0,
      matchTime:0,
      homeClubId:608,
      homeClub:{  
         clubId:608,
         clubName:"Annaba"
      },
      awayClubId:609,
      awayClub:{  
         clubId:609,
         clubName:"Bazer Sakhra"
      },
      leagues:[  
         {  
            leagueId:65,
            parentLeagueId:null,
            leagueName:"ALGERIA"
         },
         {  
            leagueId:66,
            parentLeagueId:65,
            leagueName:"Algeria Cup"
         }
      ]
   },
];

const result = data.map(o => {
  if (o.leagues) {
    o.leaguesGeneral = o.leagues.map(({ leagueName }) => leagueName).join(' - ');
  }
  return o;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Very quick answer! Thank you :)